# Does litotes need to be negative?

Tags: grammar, figures-of-speech, litotes

For example, are the following examples of litotes:

> Ariel (The Tempest): ‘[The powers, delaying, not forgetting](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/tempest/tempest.3.3.html)’

(Stresses a past injustice being remembered)

> Adam (Paradise Lost): ‘[nothing lovelier can be found / In woman, than to study household good](http://knarf.english.upenn.edu/Milton/pl9.html)’

(Stresses the best attribute in a women is maintaining a household)

Or is litotes  more confined to 'not bad', 'not unlike', etc.?

Comment: Litotes is fundamentally an understatement.  Especially when expressed as a negation of the contrary:  "He's a man of no small means." -> He's very rich.  I don't see how any of your statements can be litotic at all.

Comment: @Jim I see. What would the statements be in that case? (using a negative in order to emphasize)

Comment: Perhaps a visit to the Forest of Rhetoric would help: http://rhetoric.byu.edu/

Comment: @Icy Thank you that link. I didn't know about the Forest of Rhetoric before but I will certainly be using it in the future. Unfortunately, I can't find anything that explains this other than the term 'Correctio' (but, this is more of a corrective extension to a sentence). Would this term work for the first quote? Could you say it 'corrects' delaying? I'm not sure if this is stretching the definition too far. Or is there a better term that could be used? I would appreciate your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Thank you. I'm interested in rhetoric but it wasn't one of my "r's".  Reading the linked Milton from line 204 to about 260 puts your quoted line in a little better context.  Adam's reply starting at about 226 enumerates praise for Eve' beauty, skill, thought and expression: these last including "...nothing lovelier..." without irony in my opinion. I can't offer much help with a figure.

Comment: Much later in the day... I attended an event which involved a hour's drive each way which has given opportunity for some reflection.  Is there an allegorical framework that Milton is honouring?  The reference to "household" seems unusual and out of place given the narrative and experience in the garden.

Comment: @Icy OED: Household (n.) †2. The action of maintaining a house or family; housekeeping; domestic economy. Obsolete. The idea is that in accordance with Gen:2:18 Eve is created as an assistant to Adam. She does all the small jobs:cleaning, cooking, gathering food, etc, whilst Adam puts the finishing touches to God's Work Gen:2:19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your examples are litotes, but let me answer your main question: **Does litotes need to be negative?** It depends on how strictly you want to define the word. According to *some* sources, no, it doesn't **need to be**, although a negative construction is the most common form.

Some sources do define a litotes as requiring an overt negative. One example is [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/litotes):

> Ironical understatement in which an affirmative is expressed by the
>   negative of its contrary (e.g. *I shan’t be sorry* for *I shall be
>   glad*).

From a quick review of other sources, it would seem that this strict "traditional" definition has given way to a looser approach where negation appears to be optional. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/litotes):

> noun, plural litotes. Rhetoric.
>   1. understatement, especially that in which an affirmative is expressed by the negative of its contrary, as in “not bad at all.”.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) gives a more comprehensive summary, including the following:

> Litotes is a form of understatement, always deliberate and with the
>   intention of emphasis. However, the interpretation of negation may
>   depend on context, including cultural context.

It seems reasonable, therefore, to say that litotes always requires both understatement and negation, but the negation may be implicit rather than overt. Appropriately, [The Forest of Rhetoric](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/of%20Overstatement.htm) (thanks @Icy for the link) offers two examples of litotes, one of which lacks the overt negation-of-opposite element:

> *It isn't very serious. I have this tiny little tumor on the brain.*
>   —J.D. Salinger, The Catcher in the Rye

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. In that case, would you have any insights on the quotes in the question? Using the definitions in your answer, it seems that you cannot class them as litotes. But, what would you call when you use a negative in order to emphasize? (e.g. in the first quote, 'remembering' could have been used instead of 'not forgetting'). I've looked through the Forest of Rhetoric but found nothing that explains this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood: "not forgetting" is **not** the same as "remembering". Ariel is telling the three men that their "foul deed" against Prospero has finally caught up with them; it's not that their crime is only now being remembered, but rather that Fate has calmly waited for the opportunity to punish them. I wouldn't describe this first quote as "using a negative in order to emphasize". There's no emphasis, just a statement.

Comment: However, I think you ask a good question *in your comment* - "what would you call when you use a negative in order to emphasize?" Why don't you ask this as a separate question, using your second example? NB: you'll increase your chances of upvotes if you cite the source, i.e. Milton's *Paradise Lost*. Lastly, I'll edit my answer to confirm that the examples aren't litotes, although that wasn't what the question asked in the title. PS **If you think my post adequately answers what you asked, feel free to give it your "tick"** :-)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the situation. I was just doing a bit more research before adding it as a separate question but I've now done that. In regards to the Ariel quote, I might have misspoke when I said 'remembrance'. I meant to say that the 'foul dead' has been remembered since it was done. It was never forgotten. Not that it was just remembered. Anyway, on second thoughts, would it be correct to say it's an example of 'Correctio'? So, it amends the 'delaying'? Or would this be stretching the definition too far?

Comment: (let me know if this warrants further discussion and thus might be better for a separate question)